# Как наложить на вариардик ограничение по принимаемым типам?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Пусть есть такая конструкция:

```
template<typename T>
class SomeClass {
  template<typename... Args>
  SomeClass(Args& ...args) {}
};
```

Каким образом можно "уговорить" компилятор принимать в пакет **только** одинаковые типы, и как указать конкретный тип (пусть, например, double)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045617/check-for-arguments-type-in-a-variadic-template-declaration

Что-то похожее вроде бы

Comment: А нужен ли вариадик тут вообще? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16338804/2076787

Comment: Есть различные способы передавать переменное число аргументов. Мне нужен вариардик.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Вопрос решен**

Помогло чтение "Язык программирования С++. Лекции и упражнения. 6-е издание, 2012 год, Сивен Пратта".

Методика, как оказалось, незатейлива - рекурсивная распаковка и чек каждого аргумента пака. Получилось два варианта, но со static_assert'ом, имхо, лучше - более осмысленный вывод. В качестве эксперимента проверяем агрументы на соответствие std::size_t.

**Вариант 1 (static_assert):**

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Пример проверки передачи беззнаковых аргументов в конструктор
// Вариант 1 (используем static_assert)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename T>
class SomeClass {
  public:
    template<typename... Args>
    SomeClass(const Args& ...args) {
      UnPack(args... );
    }
  private:
    template<typename First, typename... Last>
    void UnPack(const First& F, const Last&... L) {
      UnPack(F); UnPack(L...);
    }
    template<typename First>
    void UnPack(const First& Value) {
      static_assert(std::is_same<First,std::size_t>::value,"Type mismatch!");
      std::cout << Value << ":";
    }
};

int main() {

  // норм - передаётся нужный тип
  std::size_t i=1,j=2,k=3;
  SomeClass<int> S1(i,j,k);

  // норм - передаются беззнаковые константы
  SomeClass<std::string> S2(1u,2u,3u);

  // фэйл - знаковые типы не проходят
  // int a=1,b=2,c=3;
  // SomeClass<bool> S3(a,b,c);

  return 0;
}
```

**Вариант 2 (std::enable_if):**

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Пример проверки передачи беззнаковых аргументов в конструктор
// Вариант 2 (используем std::enable_if)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename T>
class SomeClass {
  public:
    template<typename... Args>
    SomeClass(const Args& ...args) {
      UnPack(args... );
    }
  private:
    template<typename First, typename... Last>
    void UnPack(const First& F, const Last&... L) {
      UnPack(F); UnPack(L...);
    }
    template<typename First>
    void UnPack(const First& Value, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<First,std::size_t>::value>::type* = 0) {
      std::cout << Value << ":";
    }
};

int main() {

  // норм - передаётся нужный тип
  std::size_t i=1,j=2,k=3;
  SomeClass<int> S1(i,j,k);

  // норм - передаются беззнаковые константы
  SomeClass<std::string> S2(1u,2u,3u);

  // фэйл - знаковые типы не проходят
  // int a=1,b=2,c=3;
  // SomeClass<bool> S3(a,b,c);

  return 0;
}
```

В принципе, вопрос решен. Однако, если будут более изящные варианты - вэлкомъ! :)

Answer (score 1):

На C++20 можно сделать так:

```
template <std::same_as<double> ...Args>
SomeClass(Args &... args) {}
```

Или вот так, но тогда параметры нужно будет сначала скастовать в `double`:

```
template <std::convertible_to<double> ...Args>
SomeClass(Args &... args) {}
```